# How to import many .txt files in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have 250 .txt files in a folder. I want to import each file into separate worksheets. I have a worksheet which name is "Veri" in order to have a list of datas.

list of the data example:

```
HLPA01  "TEXT;C:\Users\utku.arslan\Desktop\Esat\HLPA01.txt"
HLPA02  "TEXT;C:\Users\utku.arslan\Desktop\Esat\HLPA02.txt"
HLPA03  "TEXT;C:\Users\utku.arslan\Desktop\Esat\HLPA03.txt"
HLPA04  "TEXT;C:\Users\utku.arslan\Desktop\Esat\HLPA04.txt"
HLPA05  "TEXT;C:\Users\utku.arslan\Desktop\Esat\HLPA05.txt"
HLPA06  "TEXT;C:\Users\utku.arslan\Desktop\Esat\HLPA06.txt"
```

and also wrote this VBA code.

Probably my mistake is about using "location_string" and "data_name" under "with"

```
Sub Deneme_1()
Dim location_string As String
Dim data_name As String

Sheets("Veri").Select

For i = 1 To 5
Sheets("Veri").Select
location_string = Range("b" & (i + 1))
data_name = Range("a" & (i + 1))

Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "location_string", Destination:=Range( _
        "$A$1"))
        .Name = "data_name"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 65001
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
        , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `location_string` and `data_name` are variables (type `String`). They shouldn't be in quotes. Change: `With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= "location_string", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))` to `With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= location_string, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))` and `.Name = "data_name"` to `.Name = data_name`

Comment: I did but still have error message on 

"  With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        location_string, Destination:=Range( _
        "$A$1"))"

Comment: Please copy what i mentioned in my previous comment. You have a **"_"** which shouldn't be there (`..Connection:= _ location_string..`)

Comment: I did but did not work.

Comment: You also have an underscore here which shouldn't be there: `Range( _ "$A$1")`. Also, what is the actual error you are getting and on which line?

Comment: Yes sure I've already deleted it. The error message is: Rum-time error'9': Subscript out of range